# Passing an element back with swift issue

Tags: swift

I am having some issues and am just really lost so this is a last resort.

I have this function:

```
func fetchGoogleData(forLocation: CLLocation) {
    //guard let location = currentLocation else { return }
    googleClient.getGooglePlacesData(location: forLocation) { (response) in
        self.listResults(places: response.results)
    }
}
```

Which calls this functions:

```
func listResults(places: [Place]) {
   dump(places)
}
```

However, dumping `responses.result` or `places` return a null value but looping through `places` returns all the correct values.

Is there a way to return `response.results` as the value without calling this function?

Comment: Where/when are you dumping `responses.result` and `places`? Where/when are you looping through `places`?

Comment: @rmaddy Just using dump() function and looping through places in ListResults as `for place in places {` as this displays it perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use completion block [(Closures)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) to return your results. Let say your `response.results` is of type `[Place]`. Then your function should be like below

```
func fetchGoogleData(forLocation: CLLocation, completion: @escaping [Place]->Void) {
    //guard let location = currentLocation else { return }
    googleClient.getGooglePlacesData(location: forLocation) { (response) in
        completion(response.results)
    } 
}
```

and call it as below:

```
self.fetchGoogleData(forLocation: currentPosition) { (places) in
     //print(places)
}
```

Comment: I get this error `Cannot convert value of type '[Place]' to expected argument type`

Comment: How does this work with returning the response data outside the function? Sorry, I am new to swift. `let responseData = fetchGoogleData(forLocation: currentPosition, completion: ...)`

Comment: I have updated it again. Please check. If helpful please accept and up vote :)

Comment: Life saver! Thanks so much!